# Avoid red background color for logging output in Ipython Notebook

Tags: logging, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to avoid the red background color when the notebook prints logging output? For an example see this sample notebook.

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/bjonen/1bd52a7d8a4761a74074

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The red background highlights output sent to stderr as opposed to stdout. To avoid it, you could send your logging to stdout:

```
ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
```

Comment: to get the answer to work, you'll have to replace the automatically installed log.handler with the new handler. Instead, doing `log.handlers[0].stream = sys.stdout` works for me while retaining the formatting of the default StreamHandler

Comment: If you set up logging with `logging.basicConfig`, you can also pass `stream=sys.stdout`.

Comment: If you, like me, wanted that *all log messages with a level lower than ERROR* do not have the red background, and that **ERROR and CRITICAL log messages should still have a red background**, then you might also find this useful: https://gist.github.com/joshbode/58fac7ababc700f51e2a9ecdebe563ad. You may want to adapt the `Fore.Red` into `Back.Red` and similar for the other log colors.

Comment: Or you could try to create a logger that directs ERROR and CRITICAL logs to stderr and all others to stdout...

Comment: Is there a way to just switch the red to a different color?

Answer (score 7):

The highlighted answer did not work for me. Jupyter Notebook seems to set up the logger before any imports are done. To redirect any stderr to stdout, I had to first reload the logging module:

```python
import sys
import logging
from importlib import reload
reload(logging)

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, format='',
                level=logging.INFO, datefmt=None)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.info("This should print as normal output in Jupyter, and not in a red box")
```

This can also be included in a package being imported to Jupyter Notebook, e.g. with `import my_dev_package` - and prevent log.Info being shown as red box. To only run this in Jupyter Mode (not console) for the package, add a check: `if not type(sys.stdout) == io.TextIOWrapper: # Jupyter Mode`.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet worked for me. I hated the red background and wanted it to have another color.
Here I change the background color to green, but you can set the CSS to whatever you want:

```py
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("""
<style>
div.output_stderr {
    background: #0C0;
}
</style>
""")
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because logging is logged to `stderr`

If you install the Stylus browser plugin you can change the CSS style to use a different color.

```
.jp-RenderedText[data-mime-type='application/vnd.jupyter.stderr'] {
    background: var(--jp-cell-editor-background);
}
```

Is this helpful?